# Time difference between two database time fields

Tags: delphi

If you have 3 fields in a table: Start_Time,End_Time,Time_Between
How can you calculate the difference between Start_Time and End_Time
(how much time has passed between the two) so that Time_Between field will display the difference? 
Do you need to use a calculated field for the Time_Between or can you just leave your native field to do the work?

EDIT: I would like to know if this could be done with a trigger in SQLite database for the Time_Between field.

This is what I had in mind :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TIME_DIFFERENCE]
AFTER UPDATE OF [END_TIME]
ON [MYTABLE]
BEGIN
UPDATE MYTABLE SET TIME_BETWEEN = strftime('%H',START_TIME) - strftime('%H',END_TIME) WHERE rowid=new.rowid; 
END
```

This (above example) does not work,by the way ...

Comment: I would drop that `Time_Between` field if it weren't used in frequent queries and let the app calculate that difference.

Comment: depends on your database. in some it's as simple as `select End_time - Start_Time as diff`.

Comment: Since records get bigger and bigger calculated field would slow everything down in time, so I thought of saving the result right away. I think a trigger would be more appropriate.

Comment: Don't store what you can easily calculate. If you do, you have to make sure you re-calculate every time the data changes, and update the related columns. It's also extra overhead (disk space, memory, network traffic) that isn't needed. As far as your question, that depends on the specific DBMS you're using, and neither your question or your tags mention that information. (Yes, I know you're using Absolute Database from the `ABSQuery`, but not everyone will.) Also, what is the column type you plan to use for `Time_Between`? That matters as well; do you want days, hours, minutes, weeks, months?

Comment: data wont change so that's why I avoided calculated field. Otherwise,all the mentioned fields are Time fields.I just want the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this out :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TIME_DIFFERENCE]
AFTER UPDATE OF [end_date]
ON [Table1]
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1 SET DIFF = 
cast(
         (
                  strftime('%s',Table1.end_date)-strftime('%s',Table1.start_date)
         ) AS INT
      ) / 60/60 ;
END
```

Works, as far as I can tell ....

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet:

```
var dtStartTime : TDateTime;
    dtEndTime   : TDateTime;
    dtTimeBetween : TTime;
begin
  dtStartTime := Query1.FieldByName('Start_Time').AsDateTime;
  dtEndTime := Query1.FieldByName('End_Time').AsDateTime;
  dtTimeBetween := dtEndTime - dtStartTime;
end;
```

Or you can get year, month, day, hour, minute, second from the timestamp in the database as follows.

```
   iYear := Query1.FieldByName('Start_Time').AsSQLTimeStamp.Year;
   iMonth := Query1.FieldByName('Start_Time').AsSQLTimeStamp.Month;
   iDay  := Query1.FieldByName('Start_Time').AsSQLTimeStamp.Day;
   iHour := Query1.FieldByName('Start_Time').AsSQLTimeStamp.Hour;
   ....... and so on.
```

Now you can process using these fields.

Comment: Actually the calculation is more complicated because issues such as time zones and daylight savings time come into play. Delphi's (date)time structures are all "naive" (no knowledge of time zone or DST).

Answer (score 0):

You can get time difference using following query.

```
   SELECT CAST('0:00' AS TIME) + (TO_TIME - FROM_TIME) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

This result can be used in any Update Trigger to set the time difference fie